# php Class name case sensitive

Tags: php, class, case-sensitive

I declare a class like this in php

```
<?php class Db(){  //something}
```

php has a class with name DB

when I run this code on linux OS , it works but when run it on windows, return a Fatal error.

Is php class name insensitive? 
if is insensitive , why run on linux?
if is case sensitive , why dose not run on windows?

Comment: post the error, and file name of both `Db` and `DB` class

Comment: Db.php is my own class  and DB.php on windows is on xampp/php/pear/DB.php

Comment: I have a  function in Db with name from, the error is fatal error uindefined function DB::from in php/pear/DB.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use PEAR, it time to go with `composer` if you can., for your issue you can check before defining class, if its exist extend it

```
if(class_exists('DB') != true)
  {
    class Db extends DB
    ...
    ...
    ... 
  }
```

or go with `Namespace` on php 5.3

```
namespace Core;
class Db {}
```

to call

```
\Core\Db::from();
```

or simply change the name of class

hope it helps

Comment: name space was the better choice

Comment: can you explain please?